# Reliability of Sampling Rate vs Absolute Timestamps

Tags: sensor, sampling, time

I am building a system with multiple sensors and I want to sample the different sensors at different rates. For the sake of an example, I am using two [MAX30102EFD-T](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/maxim-integrated/MAX30102EFD-T/6188734?utm_adgroup=Sensors%20%26%20Transducers&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Dynamic%20Search_EN_Product&utm_term=&utm_content=Sensors%20%26%20Transducers&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpdqDBhCSARIsAEUJ0hM4L2u0bHu9Dcu8pGnPh2nw5HKSP4V-KOoxnyFudugQG0ge2CYdPwgaAlbaEALw_wcB) sensors. One of the sensors I want to run at 50Hz and the other I want to sample at 1000 Hz. I have the ability to configure this sampling rate (samples per second) on the sensor and when each sensor has a new sample (supposedly at these frequencies), in the interrupt I can record this sensor value (and optionally record a timestamp like the number of milliseconds since boot.

As an example:

```
TIMESTAMP SENSOR VALUE
0         1      1.2
0         2      0.1
1         1      1.3
2         1      1.4
3         1      1.5
...
```

The issue is that storing timestamps along with the time series from both sensors can add significantly to the output file size. If the sampling rate of these sensors is reliable enough, I *could* just record the initial timestamp and the sampling rate and assume uniform sampling, but I'm hesitant to trust these types of sensors to have that uniform and accurate of a sampling rate. Is that distrust warranted in general?

I'm curious if anyone has any experience with such a thing and was interested to see if there was a robust approach short of storing timestamps for each sensor alongside the data.

Comment: Is there downstream processing of this data? In addition to log space, the challenge with time-stamping is that you need to include the system timer. There are certainly advantages with a good system timestamp, but there are many pitfalls in implementing it correctly. As a small aside, I would refer to what you have now as "sample index" not timestamp.

Comment: Using some kind of check to ensure you aren't missing entire  samples  is definitely a good idea, but the expected sample jitter of these devices will likely be pretty good.

Comment: @crasic Yes the resulting output will need to be processed assuming absolute timestamps. Also yes, sorry about the "timestamp" column, in our situation we will have actually timestamps there, but wanted to simplify for an example

Comment: @crasic So would you do this check in the interrupt routine and add in filler values as needed if there is too big of a gap?

Comment: It's hard to answer those questions without knowing the nature of the downstream pipeline. Generally though, using filler values is not reliable. My philosophy is there is at least one output stream that is a true, unadulterated representation of the underlying sampling, using whatever schema, protocol, and to whatever granularity that makes sense for your downstream processing and the application . Then you backtrack to implementation details such as "what if we skip a sample"  and "what kind of timestamp do we need" from there.

Comment: If you're hoping to correlate the data from multiple sensors, you're going to have to timestamp the samples. The accuracy of the sensor's internal timebase is only on the order of a few percent.

Comment: @Suever I have a rock solid rule for any instrument I build: ***The sample timing -- the time between ADC samples -- is as unvarying as I can possibly make it and, if the instrument also generates a DAC output then the DAC output will have the shortest possible processing time between ADC input and DAC output and this short time will also be as unvarying as I can possibly make it.*** The reason, if no other, is that the data (whether gathered by sampling the DAC or by separate means) may be subject to an FFT. It is my job to make sure that such FFTs will perform as well as is possible.

Comment: @Suever Each separate instrument will have separate clocking systems (crystal controlled, usually.) So within a given instrument, the above rule works okay. I can emit an I/O pin pulse that can be observed to accurately work out the time between samples, which can be slightly different from instrument to instrument (and therefore calibrated, as needed.) All of these rules have served me very well, even when faced with client requirements I could never have otherwise anticipated. So all of this forms the basis for many questions I'd have about your circumstance.

Comment: @Suever When you write "absolute time" to me, this tends to mean that you may need a way of calibrating each instrument so as to be able to establish known relationships in time between their respective measurements, as well as being able to assign an absolute basis to them, too. How important is it that the time stamps "co-ordinate" in a known way? Are these data being combined and processed in a certain fashion we need to be aware of? Etc.

Comment: @jonk Thanks for the insight. We have a number of sensors on a single board that all need to have the same time reference. We then take this file to an external system and do the analysis (combining these signals, signal processing, etc). We do not have to worry about the calibration of this "internal" time (time within the same board) with "external" time (from other boards for example) at all (at least not very precisely, but we'll have a RTC giving us a rough reference)

Comment: @Suever Okay. So it's all within a board. That's good. This said, you should definitely observe the rule I mentioned at the outset. PID control, which you aren't doing but which is an example case to make a point, is like trying to poke a long bamboo pole into a birdhouse hole. If the pole is long, it's hard. If the length of the pole keeps varying, it's even ***harder***. If both are happening? May as well just give up. So I keep the length of the pole exactly the same and rigorously unvarying. And I try and keep that pole as short as possible, too. (ADC to Control Output.)

Comment: @Suever In your case, that's not so much of a worry. But I would very much enforce the idea that each ADC sample is taken with an unvarying time between them. In all cases, everywhere. I tend to keep my variations down into the small numbers of nanoseconds, where possible, and never greater than 1 us sampling repeatability. I will dive into assembly if that's necessary in order to get there, where I can control the timing of a left-edge and a right-edge of a branch (C and C++ doesn't allow you to force one edge of an if to have the exact same time as a right edge.)

Comment: @Suever I use DMA where possible, as that extra hardware support makes this happen right. If not, I go the extra steps. It's always been time well spent. No exceptions.

Comment: Erlang is faster than C++ and its performance is in the nano seconds unlike c++ or even worse solutions like python. There is a growing community using erlang/elixer solutions for data acquisition because of this. –

Comment: @jonk That information is extremely helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Suever It would be cool to hear which parts are more helpful. (It helps me know what mattered more and what mattered less, for some future thoughts when someone else brings up these subjects.) But thanks so much for the kind thoughts! Appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

> If the sampling rate of these sensors is reliable enough, I could just record the initial timestamp and the sampling rate and assume uniform sampling

I spent 30 seconds looking at the datasheet (Ctrl-F "Frequency") and, well, it doesn't have an onboard crystal oscillator, so the internal clock is pretty inaccurate, and it will drift.

Therefore, using your microcontroller to create timestamps seems reasonable.
So there are two isuses: the absolute accuracy of the timestamps given by your microcontroller, and the synchronization between both sensors. If all you care about is knowing when a sample from the first sensor was acquired relative to the sample from the other sensor, so your 50 Hz and your 1000 Hz line up, then the accuracy or drift of the timestamps from the microcontroller clock isn't that important, because if it drifts, then the timestamps for both sensors will be affected equally, and the order of samples will still be the same.

If you want to know the sample was acquired on monday at 12:01:00 to the microsecond, then it's another problem.

> The issue is that storing timestamps along with the time series from both sensors can add significantly to the output file size.

Not really, you can compress it like time series databases do : by storing deltas. For example if you expect one sample every millisecond, and your timestamps are based on a 10MHz clock, then you store the first timestamp as a 32 bit value, then you store the difference between timestamps. And since that difference will always be close to 10000 (10MHz/1kHz) you can store deltas of deltas. This should get you down to 1 byte per timestamp.

It would probably be simpler to not use the free-running mode in the sensors and just run a 1ms timer in your micro, so you know the 1kHz sensor is synrhronized to the micro's internal clock, which presumably comes from an accurate crystal. Then every 20 samples, request a sample from the 50Hz sensor. Then you can be sure both sensors sampling times line up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @bobflux! Great tips on timestamps in those files, I'll do some investigation to see about implementing something such as that. Also thanks for the suggestion to use a centralized timer for the sampling instead of relying on the different sensors which will (as we add more sensors) inevitably have different accuracies and drift.